# Hide scrollbar while still being able to scroll with mouse/keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to disable browser or element scrollbar, but allow scrolling with wheel or arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-to-disable-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-allow-scrolling-with-wheel-or-a)

I want to know if it is possible to hide the scrollbar, while scrolling is still enabled with mouse/keyboard.

I tried to use CSS: `overflow: hidden;`. The effect is scrollbar disabled *and* scrolling disabled.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For future reference there is also a solution without jQuery - just have the wrapper div style contain `overflow:hidden` and use this JavaScript two-liner:

```
// get the width of the textarea minus scrollbar
var textareaWidth = document.getElementById("textarea").scrollWidth;

// width of our wrapper equals width of the inner part of the textarea
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width = textareaWidth + "px";
```

**Update**: you can use the same principle to create scrollable div without scrollbar.

Comment: Nice, but what's about browser and mobile compatibility for this ?

Comment: @cocoacoder you could always TRY it in different browsers and mobile if you're wondering... I tested on iOS and IE9 and it works fine. There's nothing too hacky about this approach, so it should be pretty cross-compatible. As long as the platform supports the scrollWidth property it will work fine.

Comment: it seems all browsers around the world supports it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollwidth.asp

Answer (score 5):

There is a jQuery plugin called [Scrollable](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/scrollable/) that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, but I suppose you could implement your own scrolling mechanism by using Javascript to capture certain keystrokes and re-position the container element accordingly with CSS.  It's going to be ugly, though!