# Hide scrollbar for mobile devices while keeping the scroll ability

Tags: android, html, css, webview

my question is almost the same with this:

[Hide the scrollbar but keep the ability to scroll with native feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635513/hide-the-scrollbar-but-keep-the-ability-to-scroll-with-native-feel)

I loaded a list style webpage to a `webview` for an android app.  I found that because of the scrollbar, there's a white space on the right side of the page.  It's annoying.  I want to hide the **scrollbar**, but keep the ability to scroll with native feel like @Gabriele Cirulli said.

I found this:

http://hynchrstn.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/hide-scrollbar-but-still-scrollable-using-css/

It works fine for pc, but for mobile devices, it causes the page horizontally scrollable, which is not acceptable.

Anybody can give me some advice?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the link you added I was able to come up with a more solid solution. 
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        [...lots of text]
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container,
.scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll {
    padding-right: 20px;
    right: -20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

What it does:

The `.container` and `.scroll` div both have the same dimensions as the body (full size), and since the body and `.container` both have `overflow: hidden` they will never show scrollbars in any direction.

The `.scroll` has an `overflow-y: scroll` so it can scroll vertically, but not horizontally. The scrollbar is pulled out of view with the `right: -20px` and I added padding of the same size so the content will always fit the screen nicely. There will be no need for the browser to let you scroll horizontally

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onrmqdwk/3/)

Tested on Android in Chrome and the native browser