# Building scrollable div without scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am trying to build a dynamic scrollable menu without scrollbar. I followed the example at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard), but still scrollbars are appearing. How can I get rid of the scrollbars? My code is at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cupidvogel/nnDCt/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for........ http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/1/

and I updated your's http://jsfiddle.net/nnDCt/2/  I just removed the width from list

Comment: Yeah it works, but it is supposed to do so. I want to know why mine isn't working!

Comment: Ummm, all you did was to remove the width declaration from the inner content. Why does it make it work, whereas in the example I posted, the width of both were mentioned and it worked fine?

Comment: coz it was 200px and exactly same width as the container. It should be either not defined or must be little greater than the width of the container..to better understand try increasing the width of div.list by 10px each time starting from 200px.

Comment: Well, it is not being perfect. The actual code had arrows at the end of the list-items, (I skipped those parts to stress on the necessary point), but when they are included, as you will find out in the same updated fiddle, the scroll works ok, but the arrows don't show up. Whereas if you include the width, scrollbars appear, with the arrows showing if you scroll right.