# hiding scroll bars when using overflow:scroll; but keep scrolling ability

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hide scrollbar while still able to scroll with mouse/keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard)

I've made a piece of UI for a web app. It's a side bar and it needs to let the user scroll through it without a scroll bar. The content is 500px high, but the container is 300px high.

I've set the container to have `overflow:scroll` but then I get scroll bars (which I expected). I know I can disable the scroll bars using `overflow:hidden` but that also disables the scrolling.

Is there a way I can allow it to scroll but disable the scroll bars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [hide scrollbar while still able to scroll with mouse/keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard/)

```
// get the width of the textarea minus scrollbar
var textareaWidth = document.getElementById("textarea").scrollWidth;

// width of our wrapper equals width of the inner part of the textarea
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width = textareaWidth + "px";
```

Or with jQuery catching of mouse scroll with the mousewheel plugin: [How can I disable a browser or element scrollbar, but still allow scrolling with wheel or arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-to-disable-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-allow-scrolling-with-wheel-or-a)