# skrollr : Horizontal scroll with smooth scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I am trying to build a site using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). This is the [jFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/GpPHx/1/) to what I have tried yet. But as you can see it doesn't work as expected when the smoothScrolling is set to true. When setting smoothScrolling = false, things like to work as bit but there are glitches.

```
skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: true,
    smoothScrolling:true
});
```

1. I want to make smoothScrolling = true, but what I am missing here.
2. Also how can I disable the vertical scroll. Giving overflow:hidden doesn't work, as it will disable skrollr. Also I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960286/976596), but I couldn't make it to work. The only thing worked is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184693/976596), but again its only for Webkit browsers. Is there any browser compatible solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To set your page to allow overflow in one direction, use overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:hidden; allowing you to create a sidescrolling page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want smooth scrolling for the `left` movement, but now for `top`. You need another wrapper element and use `data-smooth-scrolling="off"` on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/GpPHx/2/

If you want to hide the scrollbar, skrollr may not be the right choice for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know skrollr uses scrollbar to get all things arranged. I just need to hide it, not disable it. Scrolling will be working with mouse and keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Prinzhorn and thanks for the great library.
Your jsfiddle solution is perfect for Chrome, however it is still jiggy a bit in Firefox and it is completely not working for Safari. 
Can you make a suggestion for those browsers. I really want to implement horizontal scrolling, and I notice on the site of the walking dead it is working fine, however there the code is over-complicated