# Body overflow:hidden disables scroll by mouse wheel

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide default browser vertical scroll-bar like this:

**HTML**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lider-Bet.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="lider-bet-logo"></div>
        </header>

        <div id="main-wrapper">
            ...
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

.

**CSS**:

```
body    {
    background: url('../img/body-background-default.png');
    overflow: hidden;
}

header  {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    background-image: url('../img/header-background-default.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

It's working until I put `position:fixed` to `<header>` tag.

Here is [**JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/GZn9Y/)

**P.S:** On JsFiddle it's not working even without positioning `<header>` tag to `fixed`, probably this is some JsFiddle engine matter, so you can try to copy from JsFiddle to your pc and try it.

Thanks in advance.

.

**--UPDATE--**

Regarding comments I'll explain more detailed:

This page is created to display some data via monitor on the wall, so there will be no physical users, only one client which will scroll automatically on some position.

I wanted to hide scrollbar, but when I do this from CSS, than page is losing scroll option.
Also I'm trying to keep one `<header>` object fixed: when page will scroll down, this object must be on top anyway.

First I thought that this is browser issuer, but then I tried in different browsers and result is same: after hiding scrollbar I can't scroll page when I put `position:fixed` to `<header>` object.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Without scroll how the reaming document are readed. Can you explain your objective fully.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want the scrollbar hidden but for the user to still be able to scroll via scrollwheel? That won't be great for user experience.

Comment: It works for me :) Maybe it's a browser specific issue?

Comment: actually with `overflow: hidden;` there's shouldnt be scrollings allowed in most UA. I'd rather attach event that handles wheel turnings.

Comment: thanks for response. Please see my updates on question.

Comment: does it scrolls with a mouse wheel or with another way?

Comment: It doesn't scroll with anything - just stacked.

Comment: @zur4ik Sorry. I meant 'does the user do scrolls with a mouse wheel?' =) PS if so, then it could be easily achieved with JS

Comment: Actually, it will be scrolled by Javascript. But while I'll do this I need to test it and during this test process I can't scroll it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you need to show it on one monitor only, so you can optimize your view for one browser.

For example if you'll use chrome for showing on monitor, you can use `-webkit` hack to hide scroll-bar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    width: 0 !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this answer which seems to suggest this cannot be done just with css but needs a little js?

[hide scrollbar while still able to scroll with mouse/keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293650/hide-scrollbar-while-still-able-to-scroll-with-mouse-keyboard/)