# Hide horizontal scrollbar but keep scrolling possible

Tags: css

I'd like to hide the horizontal scrollbar only but keep the scrolling possible.

Questions such as [How to hide horizontal bar scrollbar but keep scroll function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014811/how-to-hide-horizontal-bar-scrollbar-but-keep-scroll-function) don't answer this correctly.

According to https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ I should be able to use `:horizontal` but it has no effect.

Demo (horizontal scrollbar is still visible in Chrome v84): https://jsfiddle.net/o5waygL7/

```
<p>test test test test test test test test test...</p>

html { width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
body { width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }

html::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal { display: none; width: 0; height: 0; }
html body::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal { display: none; width: 0; height: 0; }

p { width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background: green; }
```

Also, it seems if I remove the scrollbar for `html` then `body` starts getting it. If I remove it for `body` then `html` starts getting it... So, it should be disabled for both?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this just display none to ::-webkit-scrollbar

```css
html { width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
body { width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }

html::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal { display: none; width: 0; height: 0; }
html body::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal { display: none; width: 0; height: 0; }

p { width: 1000px; height: 1000px; background: green; }::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but it hides the vertical scrollbar too which I don't want. I want to hide only the horizontal scrollbar.