# VB NET WebView2 - Hiding Scroll Bars

Tags: .net, vb.net, webview2

I have recently started using WebView2 in my application to show SSRS reports. When I used WebBrowser it was very easy to hide the scroll bars but WebVIew2 is not so obvious. I have found the following code, is this best way to hide scroll bars or is there a better approach?

Thanks

```
 Private Sub WebView2_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebView21.NavigationCompleted, WebView22.NavigationCompleted
    If e.IsSuccess Then
        CType(sender, WebView2).ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('body').style.overflow='hidden'")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Your javascript question about the scroll bars maybe correct but have a look at for example [How to hide the scrollbar using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486387/how-to-hide-the-scrollbar-using-javascript)

Now the issue I see is that calling this on navigation complete could be too early for the HTML to be ready for you injection.

I would suggest you wait until [DOMContentLoaded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2frame.domcontentloaded?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) before executing your script.